# How to filter logcat output by time interval

Tags: android, eclipse, adt, logcat

I want to filter my logcat output messages that were logged in a specific time interval in the past.

Let's say I want to see my logcat entries between Time tag value `03-31 16:31:57.260` and `03-31 17:32:34.166`.

I would like to see this data directly on Eclipse or log it to a file (I know how to do that).

Is there any way this could be done?

Thank you

Comment: Personally, I'd log it to a file and use grep if the rule can be written as a simple regular expression, or else whip up a custom line-reader/time filter program if it cannot.  Such a tool could probably accept data piped in directly, too.  Depending if your need is one-time or recurring, you might even be able to use the search function of a pager like more or less to go to the first line of interest and then just manually read from there.

Comment: may be helpful https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/logcat.html

Comment: Did you find any answer ?